# Programatically retrieve TVs assigned to a MODX Resource by a given ID

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I'm rather new to MODX. I'm passing in a resource ID, and with that, I'd like to programatically retrieve any custom TVs used by a given resource along with its value.  Here's where I've gotten so far:

```
$resourceId = 1;
$resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $resourceId);

/ * @TODO How do I grab any dynamically created TVs/Values? */
$array[] = [
    'id' => $resource->id,
    'pagetitle' => $resource->pagetitle,
    'alias' => $resource->alias
];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own problem with some help from this resource: https://bobsguides.com/revolution-objects.html  For those of you interested, here is what I ended up with:

```
$resourceId = 1;   

$resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $resourceId);

$tvs = $resource->getMany('TemplateVars');

$array[] = [
    'id' => $resource->id,
    'pagetitle' => $resource->pagetitle,
    'alias' => $resource->alias,
];

foreach($tvs as $tv) {
    $array[0][$tv->name] = $tv->value;
}
```